# Jquery Accordion functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to `javascript` and `jquery` and I am trying to implement an accordion using `jquery`, I am trying do is on the page load the first panel should open and remaining panels should close and when I click next section in the first panel second panel should open and first should close and when I click next section in the second panel the first and second should close and when i click the last panel first one should open and remaining should close..
here is my code [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UYbMH/3/)

Comment: what have you tried so far? Your fiddle doesn't have any JS. You should look at [http://jqueryui.com/](http://jqueryui.com/) as it has a built-in accordion function.

Comment: just want to use only jquery not jquery ui

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/UYbMH/4/] sorry I am completely new to jquery..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try jquery UI,

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/UYbMH/5/)

Here [Reference](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/) 
Here is some code,

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
      <button id="first">Next Session</button>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
      <button id="second">Next Session</button>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
      <button id="third">First Session</button>
    <p>
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Jquery**:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ active: 0 });
    $("#first").click(function(){
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active", 1 );
    }); 
     $("#second").click(function(){
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active", 2 );
    }); 
    $("#third").click(function(){
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active", 0 );
    });

});
```

**Update:**

I created the accordance without jquery UI http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/UYbMH/8/
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/UYbMH/8/)

```
$("#nextsection").click(function(){

    $( ".panel__body:eq(0)" ).toggle('slow');
    $( ".panel__body:eq(1)" ).toggle('slow');
});
$("#nextsection1").click(function(){

    $( ".panel__body:eq(1)" ).toggle('slow');
    $( ".panel__body:eq(2)" ).toggle('slow');
});
$("#nextsection2").click(function(){

    $( ".panel__body:eq(2)" ).toggle('slow');
    $( ".panel__body:eq(0)" ).toggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: @user3282116 I created the accordance as you said try this http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/UYbMH/8/

Comment: how to create a generic way to implement this? If I have 5 panels do I need to write 5 click functions??

Comment: thank you very much and I appreciate it..learned some new things from your code..

Comment: without using toggle() can I do with addClass??

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/sn2VF/1/] here is my dom structure and I am trying to call two functions NextSection() and Last Section() trying to implement your code in my dom structure and it is not working..when you click next section it will open the next panel which is last section finish button..even the accordion should work if I have 3 panels before the last section..

Comment: You need to follow one structure please stick with this structure http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/sn2VF/8/ and don't use NextSection() and Last Section() functions.

Comment: Yes it is also good. But you want classes, So I gave class functionality. If you want any help for this task, I will give you instructions. Why you not accepted my answer ?

Comment: I have to use the functions because I am checking the validation using the functions...If I click the next section() button it will validate the fields inside the panel__body and it will go to next section which is next panel..when I click the last section() it will validate again and come back to first panel..I hope you understand the scenario..

Comment: Why you not using input click functionality. Already some functionality is there. You need to customize there. I mean use `if condition` for last section() and `else condition` for next section(). I hope this will help you. Anyway if you want to use  next section() and last section(), then use it no probs at all.

Comment: I tried like this [http://jsfiddle.net/sn2VF/12/] but it is not working..what will be the $(this) in the function??

Comment: thanks a lot much appreciated, I have few questions regarding the onclick="NextSection();" and onClick="LastSection();"..I am writing on click on the input type button right..why I have to write click event in the script side...Can I directly call from the input type onclick event???

Comment: yes you can write onclick event, But jsFiddle not supporting `onclick`. So I didn't help in this case.

Comment: can you please show me how to implement with onclick without jsfiddle??

Comment: @user3282116, you are not obeying the policy of stack-overflow. If you want further guide, then post your question with some code and paste the link here.